# Why profile hover menu is not working with bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**Profile hover is not working properly.**
same this is working on the other page but not on the home page I have a share code snippet to check.

[image: example image]

and if I remove the bootstrap carousel then the same code is working perfectly.
I have attached code with bootstrap carousel so you can check by removing that.

not working URL : https://pcbmagic.com/

working URL : https://pcbmagic.com/member/dashboard/cart.php

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pcbmagic.com/assets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
</head>
<body>



<section class="bg-light">
    <div class="row pl-4 pr-4 pt-2 pb-2" style="align-items: center;    box-shadow: 1px 0.5px 9px 0px rgb(188 193 192);">
        <div class="col-md-2" style="align-self: center;">
            <a href="https://pcbmagic.com/"><img src="https://pcbmagic.com/logo_s.png" style="height:75px;"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md nav-bg-custom main-menu-bar">
        <!-- <a href="/" class="navbar-brand d-flex w-50 mr-auto">Brand</a> -->
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar3">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse w-100" id="collapsingNavbar3">
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-center">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/"><!--<i class="fas fa-home"></i> -->Home</a>
                </li>
                <!--<li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="fas fa-calculator"></i> Instant Quote
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="pcb-order.php"><i class="fas fa-microchip"></i>&nbsp; PCB Laout</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="pcb-fabrication.php"><i class="fas fa-microchip"></i>&nbsp; PCB FABRICATION</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="fas fa-microchip"></i>&nbsp; PCB ASSEMBLY</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="stencil.php"><i class="fas fa-microchip"></i>&nbsp; STENCIL FABRICATION</a>
                  </div>
                </li>-->
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="https://pcbmagic.com/pcb-quote.php"><!--<i class="fas fa-puzzle-piece"></i> -->PCB Assembly</a>
                </li>
                <!--<li class="nav-item active">-->
                <!--    <a class="nav-link" href="/about-us.php">About us</a>-->
                <!--</li>-->
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact.php"><!--<i class="fas fa-address-book"></i>--> Contact</a>
                </li>

            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 pr-3" style="align-self: center;">
            <div class="float-right header-op"> 
                <a href="https://pcbmagic.com/member/dashboard/cart.php" class="btn btn-sm cart-a"  style="z-index: 999999;color: white !important;margin-bottom: 5px;"><img src="https://pcbmagic.com/assets/img/cart.png" class="cart">
                    <span class="cart-number" id="cart_count">
                    2                   </span>
                </a>
                    
                            <div class="dropdown-log">
                              <span>Hi,Vishal<i class="pl-2 fas fa-chevron-down"></i></span>
                              <div class="dropdown-log-content">
                              <div class="bg-dark py-2 mb-2">
                                    <div class="p-img">
                                        
                                    </div>
                                    <h6 class="text-center text-light">Vishal Vishwakarma</h6>
                                    <p class="text-center text-light" style="font-size:12px;">webadmin@championsemi.com</p>
                                </div>
                                <p><a href="/member/dashboard/">Dashboard</a></p>
                                <p><a href="/member/dashboard/under-review.php">My Order</a></p>
                                <p><a href="/member/dashboard/production.php">Production Status</a></p>
                                <p><a href="#">Help Center</a></p>
                                <p><a href="/member/dashboard/logout.php">Logout</a></p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                                        </div>
        
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

</body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
</head>
<body>
    

    <section class="">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <!--<li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>-->
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner" style="border: 1px solid #dedede;">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/s1.png" alt="First slide">
               
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/t2.png" alt="Second slide">
              
            </div>
            <!--<div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://pcbwayfile.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/banner/21/03/25/1808173691783t.jpg" alt="Third slide">
              
            </div>-->
          </div>
          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>
        
     </section>
    


</body>
</html>


<style>
    @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .mobile-space {margin-top:35px;}
        .carousel-inner img {height: 135px;}
        .dropdown-log-content{z-index:999999;}
        }
</style>
<section class="pt-5 ft-text-link" style="background:#1b1b1b;color:white;font-size:14px;box-shadow: 0px -3px 2px #1b1b1b;">
        <div class="container-fluid pl-5 pr-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <h6>Business</h6>
                    <ul class="ft-list">
                        <li class=""><a href="">Electronics / Semiconductors</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="">Industrial Design Services</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="">PCB/PCB-A</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="">Display and Signage Systems</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="">IoT Solutions</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="">Medical Electronics</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                        <h6>Important Links</h6>
                    <ul class="ft-list">
                        <li class=""><a href="">Careers @ ChampionSemi</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="">Ecosystem</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="">For Investors</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="">Legals</a></li>
                        <li class=""><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 newsletter">
                    <p class="text-center">Would you like to know what’s happening at the forefront of semiconductor and electronics at ChampionSemi? Sign up and receive the latest updates.</p>
                    <div class="mt-2" style="height:36px;">
                        <center><input class="m-width-100 m-mb-5 w-50" type="text" name="">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-o btn-sm m-width-100 w-50" style="font-size: 12px;
                        padding: 4px !important;">Subscribe Now</a></center>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <div class="row mobile-space">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p class="mb-1">Payment Methods</p>
                    <img style="height:23.5px;" src="https://pcbmagic.com/assets/img/payment-mode.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <p class="mb-1">Delivery Services</p>
                    <img style="height:23.5px;" src="https://pcbmagic.com/assets/img/delivery-mode.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid pl-4 pb-2 pr-4">
            
            <hr style="background:#ffffff21;width:100% !important;margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                     <!--<center class="m-display" style="display:none;"><img class="m-display-block" src="https://geocon.in/smartnet/logo-ft.png" style="height:27px;"></center> -->
                    <p class="pl-1 m-text-center"><!--<img class="m-hide" src="https://geocon.in/smartnet/logo-ft.png" style="height:27px;">--> PCBMagic © 2021 | <a href="http://championsemi.com/">Champion Semiconductor LLP</a> | <a href="terms-of-use.php">Terms of use </a> |  <a href="privacy-and-refund-policy.php">Privacy Policy </a></p> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 ft-fa text-right follow-ft">
                    <p class="m-text-center">Follow us 
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/geocon.smart"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/GeoconSmart"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/geoconsmart/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </p>
                    
                </div>
            
            </div>
        </div>
        
    </section>
```

Comment: have you check by removing section one by one and cross check when it will going to work.

Comment: not yet let me check and update you soon.

Comment: yes when i remove slider from home page it's working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add **z-index** property to your .dropdown-log-content class. as below

```
.dropdown-log-content
{
  z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```